# Angular Post not sending in data to mvc post method

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, http-post

```
$http.post('/DealerCriteria/GetDealerPoints', [{ "DealerId": "abc", "DealerPoints": "def" }]).success(function (results) {
                $scope.dealerpoints = results;
            });
```

Above is our post method. We are sending it static data for testing purposes.

The method it is calling is:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetDealerPoints(List<DealerPointInput> dealerPointInput)
{
    ...
}
```

dealerPointInput view model:

```
public class DealerPointInput
{
    public string DealerId;
    public string DealerPoints;
}
```

When debugging, we notice that dealerPointInput is a collection of 1, but the values for the DealerId and DealerPoints is null. It seems that the collection knows something is there but cant resolve the inner data. We have tried changing quotations around on any possible combination. Nothing seems to work. Even tried a regular Ajax post. That also doesn't work. We have to be missing something. Any suggestions?

The issue was that there were no getters and setters on the view model.

```
public class DealerPointInput
{
    public string DealerId {get; set;}
    public string DealerPoints {get; set;}
}
```

This resolved the issue.

Comment: you're calling `DealerCriteria/GetDealerPoints'` but your method is called `GetDealerPoints123`

Comment: Just found the cause. Youre right the example code is wrong. The answer to the solution is that there were no getters and setters on the view model :-). 2 Hours of debugging over a simple minor mistake.